# Can a browser display something that isn't in the markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firebug

I've got a text area, updated it.  Normally the displayed text appears in the content of that text area tag (using firebug to see what is in the current html).  I've just run into a situation where the text being displayed in the text area, doesn't appear in the content (at least according to firebug).  I also cannot find the text via jquery, so jquery says there isn't anything there either.  However the browser is displaying something in that text area.

What are the ways this could be happening?

Here is the markup from firebug:

```
<textarea id="HotlineComment" class="text autogrow valid" rows="2" name="HotlineComment" cols="20" style="overflow: hidden; resize: none; height: 30px;" title="Enter the reason for this change"></textarea>
<span class="authError" for="HotlineComment" generated="true"></span>
```

Here's the visual that Firefox is presenting:
[image]

Comment: clear your cache it will be fine

Comment: Yes. Through CSS pseudo-elements and the `content` property, with external media such as images, ...

Comment: The "values" of inputs shown in inspect element do not usually represent the current value. Instead, they represent the default value.

Comment: Search for that particular text in your complete project and go through each matched file.

Comment: _"I also cannot find the text via jquery, so jquery says there isn't anything there either."_. What code are you using to attempt this?

Comment: jQuery should be able to get you your code: `$('#HotlineComment').val()`

Comment: Some additional information: it appears that when a jquery event adds something (or removes something) from the displayed page, firebug does not reflect that change.  Is this the case generally?

Comment: Jquery that is supposed to grab this new text (it's called from the text area's blur event:
`    if ($('#HotlineComment').text()) {
        if ($('#HotlineComment').text().length == 0) {
            $('#hotlineReasonTextContainer span').text('No reason entered.');
        } else {
            $('#hotlineReasonTextContainer span').text($('#HotlineComment').text());
        }
    }`

Comment: I've also tried `$('HotlineComment').val() with the same non-result.  Sorry about not getting the 'code' backticks to format the above comment.  That doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: I simplified the code to see what was just entered.  It is now `console.log("$('#HotlineComment').val() is: " + $('#HotlineComment').val());` and it always returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically textareas do not put in all their content in the HTML. They are contained within the  `element` in the DOM, not necessarily reflected in the Code.

You can still access the values.

Try using:

1. `$('#HotlineComment').val()` to fetch the value.
2. `$('#HotlineComment').val('New Value Here')` to change value.

I tried replicating it on Stackoverflow, so when you type into the answer box, the HTML still shows just:

```
<textarea id="wmd-input" class="wmd-input processed" name="post-text" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="101" data-min-length=""></textarea>
```

Whereas when I do a `$('#wmd-input').val()` I can see the entire content in the console.

Further reads:

1. http://www.sophox.com/wordpress/?p=921
2. http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/form-textarea-example.htm

Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks.  What would explain the `$('#wmd-input').val()` returning nothing after the user has typed into the text area and the text area is displaying this text?  That's the situation I find myself in.

Comment: That should not happen, could you tell me what exact environment you are using? Do you replicate the same problem on StackOverflow site too?

Comment: This turned out to be the most helpful.  Knowing that this should not happen pointed me in another direction. It turned out that the jQuery validation plugin was blocking me from getting that information via jQuery.

Comment: That is great, always make sure you verify such problems on different environments to narrow down your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The text in `textarea` would have have added / changed through client scripting language e.g. `javascript`  Browsers do not change at their own.

[*Through javascript*](http://jsfiddle.net/kFPUx/)

```
document.getElementById('HotlineComment').value = 'changed';
```

Comment: That is what I initially assumed as well.  However, in my situation, I can't find the text even using jquery to find get the val() of the text area.  Still the text area is displaying the new text in the browser.